# Prove that the following cubic polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $a\neq b$  $|a,b  \in\mathbb N$  and let $P(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+1$
>
> Show that $P$  is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

I tried writing $(x^2+dx+e)(x+f)=x^3+ax^2+bx+1$ to find a contradiction. Found that $f$ is rational and $f=1/e$.

Comment: I have tried proof by contradiction- $(x^2+dx+e)(x+f)=x^3+ax^2+bx+1$ and playing with that, with no luck

Comment: Good! What can you say about the value of f?

Comment: $f$ is rational and $f=1/e$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint.* As $P(x)$ has degree $3$, if it were reducible, it would have a linear factor, i.e. it would have a rational root. This root can only be $1$ or $-1$, because the constant term is $1$ as well as the highest degree term coefficient. Then see if it is compatible with what you know about $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I thought about it at first, but I don't quite understand why it must be 1 or -1
look at the comments of the Q: $f=\frac{1}{e}$ and $f$ is a rational

Comment: Do you know the Rational Root Theorem?

Comment: There's a theorem about rational roots of a polynomial with integer coefficients: if this root is $p/q$ (in irreducible form)., $p$ must be a divisor of the constant term, and $q$ a divisor of the highest degree term coefficient. So here, you haven't that many possibilities…

Comment: I do now :), that was the missing link